# Getting a "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first" error

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, sqldatareader

Even though I call `close()` on the reader, I still get the following error message:

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first

It is only happening when there are 2 or more empty Document_No fields.

```
if (textBoxDocNum.Text == "")
{
    SqlConnection baglanti = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=E:\Visual\sw\sw\DMSDataBase.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
    baglanti.Open();
    SqlCommand emir = new SqlCommand("SELECT Document_No, Doc_IDN FROM Details WHERE Document_No = ''", baglanti);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(emir);
    da.Fill(dt);

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        SqlCommand emir2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT Class, Type, Title, State, Date, Status FROM Document WHERE IDN = "+dr["Doc_IDN"].ToString(), baglanti);
        SqlDataReader dr2 = emir2.ExecuteReader(); //it explodes here
        dr2.Read();
        if (dr2[0].ToString()==comboBoxClass.Text && dr2[1].ToString() == comboBoxType.Text && dr2[2].ToString() == textBoxTitle.Text && dr2[3].ToString() == State && dr2[5].ToString() == Status)
        {
            labelDuplicate.Visible = true;
            return 0;
        }
        dr2.Close();
        baglanti.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Before you do *anything* else, you should stop building SQL like this. Start using parameterized SQL. Next, try closing the *command*, not just the reader. Third, use `using` statements instead of calling `Close()` manually.

Comment: +1 @JonSkeet (especially if you are returning early like you do... using would dispose properly even if you hit the return 0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue might be that when you return from inside the `if` statement, the reader will not be closed.

You should change your code to use `using` statements. That will close your reader even if you return. The same is true for the connection.

Your code has another flaw. I believe readers require an open connection. The first pass around the loop will close the connection if the condition is false, making the second pass fail.